# Datagridview - remove part before the first column

Tags: winforms, user-interface, datagridview, appearance

I was wondering if when using the datagridview control you can remove the thing that looks like a column before the 1st column. I think its used to select rows but not sure what its called.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Here is a solution for standard windows controls in C#.

To hide the row headers you can use the property `RowHeadersVisible` and set it to false.

To make the row headers smaller you can use the property `RowHeadersWidth`.

Comment: it actually is RowHeadersVisible and not RowHeaderVisible; tried to update post but it weren't enough modified characters...

Comment: A link to the windows forms `DataGridView` `RowHeadersVisible` property msdn documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I wonder why do we need to click the column though!
Any idea how to hide it by-default? Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Set the RowHeadersVisible property to False and it will work like a charm